# What is the difference between using comma and dot specifying decimal numbers?

Tags: vb.net

Hello I am trying to make a simple calculator in vb.net but I have little problem. The problem is when I added double numbers each other such as 4.3+1. When I use dot for double numbers like that --> 4.3 it works perfectly. But when I use comma to specify double such as --> 4,3 it doesn't work.It reads the number like 43 not the 4,3 Here is my code:

```
Label3.Text = Val(CDbl(TextBox1.Text)) + Val(CDbl(TextBox2.Text))
            Label3.Text = TextBox1.Text & " + " & TextBox2.Text & " = " & Label3.Text
```

[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7ncR.jpg)
[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YT6K2.jpg)

Comment: Why do you think a comma should work as a decimal place? Is this a locale issue?

Comment: But when we use comma in normal calculator it works perfectly. I mean they don't read 4,3 as 43

Comment: `Val(CDbl( ... ))` is redundant - you dont need to convert a double to a double, but you should set `Option Strict On`..  `Double.TryParse()` will work with whatever punctuation mark is legal for the prevailing culture.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: I am really beginner at vb.net so I don't know where to put "Double.TryParse()" can you make it clear?

Comment: In some countries , is used for fraction separator, but in others it's a thousands separator. It can make sense for a fancy calculator to allow both, but not in VB

Comment: so What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

The reason this is happening is that the `CDbl` function will parse around commas as though they were visual delimiters for long numbers. Take this for example:

```
Sub Main
    Dim val = "3,000"
    Dim dVal = CDbl(val)
    Console.WriteLine(dVal) ' Outputs 3000
End Sub
```

Unless you know for certain that commas will always be used as a decimal value you wouldn't be able to determine whether or not this is the number `3.000` or `3000`

You could replace the `,`s in your text with `.`s, like so:

```
Sub Main
    Dim val = "3,000"
    Dim dVal = CDbl(val.Replace(",","."))
    Console.WriteLine(dVal) ' Outputs 3
End Sub
```

This will, however, fail as soon as someone tries to enter a number like `3,000,000`

Alternatively, if you happen to know the culture you'll be parsing for ahead of time, you can do something like this.

```
Sub Main
    Dim val = "3,000,000.00"
    Dim deVal = "3.000.000,00"
    Console.WriteLine(Double.Parse(val)) ' Outputs 3000000
    Console.WriteLine(Double.Parse(deVal, New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE"))) ' Outputs 3000000
End Sub
```

The current culture for the machine is used in the first `Parse`, which in my case is "en-US". By specifically using the "de-DE" culture, the `Parse` handles the alternative number style.

Comment: Isn't the delimiter determined by the locale of the system?

Comment: Will it correct if I declare them inside public class such as: dim num1, num2 as doouble. And and num1=textbox1.text, num2=textbox2.text and correct my code like: 'Label3.Text = Val(num1) + Val(num2)
            Label3.Text = num1 & " + " & num2 & " = " & Label3.Text'

Comment: sorry it wasn't clear. Here what I mean, I made it but it stil didn't work https://imgur.com/a/NKET9

Comment: Your wider issue is this: if the user enters `1,234`, how will you know if they mean `1234` or `1.234`?

Comment: yeah. But I want to be honest I didn't understand your codes.. I mean I got it little bit, but how can I make them usefull for my code?